# Failed to Load ECDSA P521 Host Key on Windows SSH Server

Tags: windows-10, powershell, openssh, ssh-keys, sshd

I am trying to generate an ecdsa p521 host key on my Windows 10 SSH Server as my client only supports ecdsa 521 key. Thus, I have used the following steps but I failed to load the p521 host key from the Server.

1.Run the followinging from Power Shell as admin user

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen.exe -C system -b 521 -o -t ecdsa -f C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_ecdsa_p521_key
```

2. Modify sshd_config to add

   ```
   HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_p521_key
   KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp521
   HostKeyAlgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
   ```
3. Restart-Service sshd from Power Shell

   ```
   Restart-Service : Failed to start service 'OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)'.
   At line:1 char:1
   Restart-Service sshd
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) 
   [Restart-Service], ServiceCommandException
   FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand
   ```
4. Check the log from the Even Viewer

   ```
   sshd: error: Could not load host key: __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_p521_key
   ```

Concern: Look at the default host key ssh_host_ecdsa_key I found out that user name is
nt authority\system@domain_name, but the key I generated from above is user@domain_name. I am not sure if this could be the root cause

Comment: OpenSSH on Windows isn’t a 100% port of OpenSSH.  This very well might be a feature it simply doesn’t support.  Have you submitted this issue to the GitHub community for OpenSSH (Microsoft’s repository not the main repository)

Comment: “I am not sure if this could be the root cause” - it’s an issue but not what’s preventing the service from starting

Comment: overwrite the existing key files will do the trick, simply replace the p256 with p521 using  C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen.exe -b 521 -o -t ecdsa -f C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_ecdsa_key  then Restart-Service sshd

Comment: You should submit a detailed answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to rely on the existing key files

1. From the Windows search bar type Run > %programdata%
2. Click ssh one should see all the key files and ssh config files
3. Copy the path from above (should be C:\ProgramData\ssh, if not replace the C:\ProgramData\ssh with your path below in the next step
4. Open Power Shell as administrator
5. using C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen.exe -b 521 -o -t ecdsa -f C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_ecdsa_key
6. Restart-Service sshd